# Mssql: Executing store procedure where the name gets from another sp

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with a store procedure (SP) in mssql. What I have is a table where one of the columns contain a SP name and whet I have to do is getting that SP name and execute that SP inside my SP.

So what I have done:

1. I have a SP - ok
2. Declare a variable with the name of the SP that will get the SP names og the SP in the table - ok

.

```
DECLARE @rs varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = N'usp_GetSP)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @rs output
EXECUTE @rs
```

Here I know that I get the SP names when I do the EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, but the  @rs, I am not sure. I get this error:

> Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1 Procedure
>   expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'. Msg
>   2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 4 Could not find stored procedure ''.

1. Execute that SP that I get back - here is the problem

This is a SP that have three `SELECT`statements and `UNION`them and this SP is the third second `UNION`(last `SELECT` statement) that I need to get to work.

Do anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

*`For Error Message:`* I think you should declare `@sql` as nvarchar not varchar;

In your case, your assigning nvarchar value (N'usp_GetSP') gets converted to varchar as you had defined @sql as varchar type.

```
DECLARE @rs nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'usp_GetSP' --not sure why you have ')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @rs output
EXECUTE ( @rs )
```

Also [check this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499) on how to use `OUTPUT` parameters with `sp_exeutesql`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And the ')' should not been there, it was not in my code...